# SQL to JOIN on two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our CRM software has a relationship function which allows you to define a relationship between two contacts.  The contacts are stored in the `CONTACT` table and the relationship is stored in `CONTACT_CONTACT`.

We relate a doctor contact to a patient contact. In the `CONTACT_CONTACT` table there is `CONTACTID1`, `CONTACTID2`, `CONTACT1_ROLE`, and `CONTACT2_ROLE`.

We query the `CONTACT` table for the initial `CONTACT` by using a ClientID. Then we use the `CONTACTID` to do a a table join. The problem here is that the `CONTACTID` we have could be in `CONTACT_CONTACT.CONTACTID1` or `CONTACT_CONTACT.CONTACTID2` columns.

```
SELECT c2.CONTACT,
   c2.ClientID,
   c2.CONTACTID
FROM CONTACT as c
INNER JOIN CONTACT_CONTACT as cc on c.CONTACTID = cc.CONTACTID2
INNER JOIN CONTACT as c2 on cc.CONTACTID1 = c2.CONTACTID
WHERE c.ClientID = 121695 AND (cc.CONTACT1_ROLE = 'Doctor' OR cc.CONTACT2_ROLE = 'Doctor')
```

Same issue for joining back to the `CONTACT` table for the contact with  the Doctor role listed in `CONTACT_CONTACT`.

If the contact or doctor can be in either `CONTACT_CONTACT.CONTACTID1` or `CONTACTID2`, what would be the best way to go about this without the possibility of changing the database tables?

Comment: if you're only selecting information from c2, why does joining to contact twice matter?  Specifically what information are you trying to arrive at with your query?

Comment: jeez, that's a terrible way of performing this design. Can you show some sample data with the different combination of roles and contacts?

Comment: Horrid design... But show some sample data, your table schemas, and desired output please.

Comment: It's Sage ACT.  The existing database I inherited has Clients and Doctors in the same CONTACT table.

The users were relating a client to their doctor so I would use the ClientID to get the initial Contact then trying to find the relationships where one is the doctor.  Then I want to get information from the doctor so that I can use it for an invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just do the query twice?  There would be other ways to be sure, but this should get the information I think:

```
SELECT c.CONTACT,
   c.ClientID,
   c.CONTACTID
FROM CONTACT as c
INNER JOIN CONTACT_CONTACT as cc on c.CONTACTID = cc.CONTACTID1
INNER JOIN CONTACT as c2 on cc.CONTACTID2 = c2.CONTACTID
WHERE c.ClientID = 121695 
    AND cc.CONTACT1_ROLE = 'Doctor'
union
SELECT c2.CONTACT,
   c2.ClientID,
   c2.CONTACTID
FROM CONTACT as c
INNER JOIN CONTACT_CONTACT as cc on c.CONTACTID = cc.CONTACTID2
INNER JOIN CONTACT as c2 on cc.CONTACTID1 = c2.CONTACTID
WHERE c.ClientID = 121695 
    AND cc.CONTACT2_ROLE = 'Doctor'
```

I'm not really clear on what information you're hoping/attempting to get from your query, as you're only selecting from a single table's data.

Comment: I think this would solve the problem in the best sense.  I should have supplied example data.

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` should work. However, if you have values in both fields, the join will execute on the field you list first inside the parentheses.

```
SELECT c.CONTACT,
   c.ClientID,
   c.CONTACTID
FROM CONTACT as c
INNER JOIN CONTACT_CONTACT as cc on c.CONTACTID = COALESCE(cc.CONTACTID1,cc.CONTACTID2)
WHERE c.ClientID = 121695 AND (cc.CONTACT1_ROLE = 'Doctor' OR cc.CONTACT2_ROLE = 'Doctor')
```